# Elasticsearch change date format when mapping

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, elasticsearch

I am using Laravel with Elasticsearch. But I cant map my mysql timestamps since ES by default only support timestamp as ISO 8601 "2015-02-02T15:30:20"

And I want to map my timestamps that looks like "2015-02-15 15:30:22" -a TS without the "T"

Is it possible to change ES so it allows timestamps like "2015-02-15 15:30:22"?

Comment: Put your code?  Can you use PHP's str_replace or MySQL's date_format?

Comment: It's definitely possible to use [custom date formats](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#custom) in ES. You just have to specify the pattern in your mapping. I have no idea what it takes to do that with Laravel though.

Comment: The answer bellow worked. I used this package with laravel https://github.com/adamfairholm/Elasticquent - But I am not sure it supports nested objects if you need that aswell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set up a [custom date format](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) in your mapping so that it will accept the MySQL format:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test/date-format/_mapping" -d'
{
    "date-format" : {
       "properties": {
          "timestamp": {"type": "date","index": "not_analyzed","format" : "yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"}
        }
    }
}'
```

Then test it out by posting a message:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/date-format" -d'
{
      "timestamp": "2014-10-22 20:03:12"
}'
```

it should return:

```
{"_index":"test","_type":"test-date","_id":"AUuD22Ls9cHgxNzY1tfJ","_version":1,"created":true}
```

Comment: Olly, any idea how to also force support for 0000-00-00 00:00:00 default timestamps?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel timestamps are generally Carbon instances so just convert them to your [accepted format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html):

```
{
  "date-format": {
    "properties": {
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "strict_date_optional_time|| epoch_milli"   //default 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then all you need to do is

```
$unixEpochMilli = $user->created_at->timestamp * 1000;  //epoch_milli is elastic default
$isoTime = $user->created_at->toIso8601String();   //also a default
```

Bear in mind that if you're looking at the data in Kibana it defaults to the browser time for display. Just click on the JSON representation, and you'll see something like `2018-12-19T05:14:21.000Z` indicating the stored epoch.